# projection query for ndb.Expando (1.7.6)

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

the following query returns keys only even I want to return the attribute Name which is a ndb.StringProperty of a ndb.Expando entity.

`cls.query().order(cls.Name).fetch(100, projection=[cls.Name])` #.. WHAT?

If I do something like `cls.query().order(cls.Name).fetch(100)` works

Question, can I use projection over ndb.Expando? I've even tried 
`cls.query().order(cls.Name).fetch(100, projection=[ndb.GenericProperty('Name')])` and get only keys plus null values for the other properties in the result.

I'm on 1.7.6. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your class definition? Did you get an exception or just unexpected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. They all indexed by default. Just define them as strings.

```
cls.query().fetch(100, projection=['name'])

# next one also will work
cls.query().fetch(100, projection=[ndb.GenericProperty('name')])
```

This will work only without order by generic property.

Comment: Yes, I figured that removing the order() works either way. Why I can't use the order?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can order only by explicit properties.

Comment: Weird. I have another ndb.expando entity a bit more complex and I'm able to apply the order.